# Python : rcvfrom() doesn't work in Linux

Tags: python, linux, sockets, udp

The below mentioned part of the UDP client program works fine with windows and looks like rcvfrom() function is stuck in linux. Using tcpdump i can see the packets arriving on the interface. I've turned off checksum/offload on this interface as well.

```
packet = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
packet.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
frame_count = 0

while True :
    try:
        data= packet.recvfrom(65536)#[0:16] # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        frame_count = frame_count + 1 
        data_rx(data,frame_count)
```

Comment: Are you sure that iptables isn't discarding those packets? Can you do "iptables -F all" and see what happens ?

Comment: Cool, this helped ! what is this to do with iptables -F ??? thanks

Comment: Ok, see the answer. Hope it'll be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, on Linux when you've iptables (IPv4 packet filtering and NAT-ing tools, by configuring it you can drop or accept packets on Linux) enabled the default configuration drops the UDP packets. To fix the issue do the followings:

```
       iptables -F all
```

What it does is, flush all the iptables which allows udp packets but remember on production systems don't do it with "iptables -F all" (it flushes all the chains available), instead find out the chain which causes to drop the packet and fix that chain.